# How to return an instance's attribute by default

Tags: python

In my code, I have a data store with multiple variables set to instances of a class similar to that below. (The reason is that this `Interval` class has lots of operator overriding functions).

```
class Interval(object):

    def __init__(self, value):
         self.value = value


data_store.a = Interval(1)
```

I want any references to `data_store.a` to return `self.value` rather than the `Interval` instance. Is this possible?

Comment: So are `data_store` and `data_store.a` both Interval objects?

Comment: No, it isn't; `data_store.a` will always give you the `Interval` instance, not its `value` attribute.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I know, he need to extend the class of the `data_store` object in order to accomplish this. See below.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi good point - I should have been clearer that I meant that it can't be done by modifying `Interval`.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to [Malik's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29244392/3001761), you could make `a` a `@property`, the Pythonic equivalent of `get` and `set` for managing access to internal attributes:

```
class DataStore(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.a = Interval(1)

    @property
    def a(self):
        return self._a.value

    @a.setter
    def a(self, value):
        self._a = value
```

Here `_a` is a *private-by-convention* attribute that stores the `Interval` instance. This works as you want it:

```
>>> store = DataStore()
>>> store.a
1
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend your data store whose attribute is an interval object:

```
class DataStore(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.a = Interval(1)

    def __getattribute__(self, attr):

        if attr == 'a':
            return object.__getattribute__(self, 'a').value

        if attr != 'a':
            return object.__getattribute__(self, attr)
```

Comment: It might be neater to make `a` a `@property`, managing access to an internal `_a` attribute, rather than patching `__getattribute__`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I am only 16 and I still have much to learn about Python. Decorators and properties are definitely on my bucket list of things to dive into.

Comment: Fair enough; I have added an alternative answer to show how that would look